# InverseErf series expansion

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

In the [*Mathematica* 11.1 documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseErf.html#11523), they have given the following series expansion of the inverse error function. My question is: how does *Mathematica* compute it? Does it do an approximation of this series? If yes, how many terms do they include? Thanks.

```
Series[InverseErf[z], {z, 0, 10}]

(* (Sqrt[π] z)/2 + 1/24 π^(3/2) z^3 + 7/960 π^(5/2) z^5 + (127 π^(7/2) z^7)/80640 +
   (4369 π^(9/2) z^9)/11612160 + O[z]^11 *)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For inverse functions like `InverseErf[]`, the usual approach for determining their series coefficients is [Lagrangian inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem). (That is, what `InverseSeries[]` does.)

In particular, *Mathematica* supports the [(partial) Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials) that appear in the series coefficients for the inverse series as `BellY[]`. (See also the discussion in [Charalambides's book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=PDMGA-v5G54C&pg=PA433).) Using this, along with the general formula for the derivative of `Erf[]` (formula 7.1.19 in [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_298.htm)), we have

```
SetAttributes[inverseErfCoefficient, Listable];
inverseErfCoefficient[0] = 0; inverseErfCoefficient[1] = Sqrt[π]/2;
inverseErfCoefficient[m_Integer?Positive] :=
       (Sqrt[π]/2)^m BellY[Table[{(m + k - 2)!, (-2)^k/(2 k) Sqrt[π]/Gamma[1 - k/2]},
                                 {k, 2, m}]]/(m! (m - 1)!)
```

Test:

```
inverseErfCoefficient[Range[0, 7]]
   {0, Sqrt[π]/2, 0, π^(3/2)/24, 0, (7 π^(5/2))/960, 0, (127 π^(7/2))/80640}

Sum[inverseErfCoefficient[k] x^k, {k, 0, 20}] - (InverseErf[x] + O[x]^21)
   O[x]^21
```

---

As it turns out, the series coefficients for the Taylor expansion of the inverse error function at $0$ satisfy a simple nonlinear recurrence. The formulae used in the following are adapted from [Carlitz](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103035736) and [Dominici](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607230):

```
ck[0] = 0; ck[1] = 1;
ck[n_Integer?Positive] := ck[n] = 2 Sum[Binomial[n - 1, k] ck[k - 1] ck[n - k], {k, n - 1}]

SetAttributes[inverseErfCoefficient, Listable];
inverseErfCoefficient[m_Integer?NonNegative] := (Sqrt[π]/2)^m ck[m]/m!
```

This version should give the same results.

Comment: An example of why your answers are among my favorites. +1

Comment: Glad to know you like it! I try my best when it comes to special functions...

Comment: Thanks @J.M., I tested the code . It answers my question. However for larger values of x, say x=.9, I have to keep k=61 which is high. For x=.99 value of k is really high and it takes more time to compute so I was looking at the alternative . I came across another approximate formula on wikipedia, nand tested ,  it works better. it goes like this: anotherErfInv[x_] := 
 Sqrt[Sqrt[(2/(.147 Pi ) + Log[1 - x^2]/2)^2 - 
     Log[1 - x^2]/.147] - (2/(.147 Pi) + Log[1 - x^2]/2)]. This works better.

Comment: @nutan, two things you need to remember: 1. a Taylor series is usually only  accurate for values near its expansion point; and 2. no polynomial has ever had a vertical asymptote. Mull on those two statements, and then think about what you were doing again when you were evaluating at $x\approx 1$

Comment: @J.M. : You are right on both points,  but in my application the variable takes values between -1 and 1. So I had to consider it. Besides, the application goes further.

Comment: My point was that by its nature, any Taylor-based method will not perform well near $\pm 1$, @nutan, and thus you indeed have to use a different method. That is for you to investigate.

Comment: This paper may be of interest:  http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1976-30-136/S0025-5718-1976-0421040-7/S0025-5718-1976-0421040-7.pdf    Though free access to the body of the paper is given at the AMS archive, the contents of the 62-page microfiche supplement (comprising 88 tables of rational approximants) are not present there.