# Expansion of standard inverse normal cdf

Tags: series-expansion, distributions

Let $\Phi: x\rightarrow y$ be the CDF of a standard normal distribution. The range of $\Phi(x)$ is $[0,1]$ and the domain is all real numbers.

I want to get a series expansion of $\Phi^{-1}(y)$ around $y=0$. I know that the first term should be $-\sqrt{2\ln(y)}$ and would like to know what the higher order terms are.

I tried

```
f[y_] := InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], y]
Series[f[y], {y, 0, 5}]
```

But the result is not a series expansion as expected. There are constant terms like $\log(\frac{1}{2\pi})$ and I'm not sure why they're there since $y\rightarrow 0$. How do I obtain the corrections to the $-\sqrt{2\ln(y)}$ term?

Comment: Use ``FullSimplify`` on the result to obtain ``-Sqrt[-2 Log[y] - Log[-2 π Log[2 π y^2]]] + ...``

Comment: @Domen thanks! It's a bit annoying that the $\log\log$ term is stuck under the square root - is there a way to separate it from the $\sqrt{-2\log y}$ term?

Comment: Well, you can do some funky expression manipulation to remove the other $\log$, like: ``FullSimplify[Series[f[y], {y, 0, 1}]] /. Log[_ Log[_]] :> 0``. But since you mention that you also want to get [higher-order terms](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.17#iii): I am afraid this is not _directly_ possible in Mathematica. You can see that the expansion is the same, no matter how many terms you specify in ``Series``. That is because Mathematica uses its [tabulated series](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseErfc/06/02/) for ``InverseErfc`` at $x\to0$, which is a fixed expression.

Comment: Please, take a look at the similar question: [_How to get more terms with the `Series[]` expansion of `InverseErf[x]` around x=1?_](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271157/how-to-get-more-terms-with-the-series-expansion-of-inverseerfx-around-x-1), and the corresponding answer by @user293787.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, mea culpa, I got it wrong.

Try 2:

```
n = 9; 
domain = Chop[N[Range[2^(-n), 0.9999999999, 2^(-n)]]]; 
data = Transpose[{domain, InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], domain]}]; 
indices = (ToString[PaddedForm[#1, 2, NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}]] & ) /@ Range[0, n]; 
symbols = (Symbol[StringJoin["x", #1]] & ) /@ indices; 
expr = symbols . (ChebyshevT[#1, x] & ) /@ Range[0, Length[indices] - 1]; 
result = FindFit[data, expr, symbols, x]; 
function = Function[x, Evaluate[FullSimplify[expr /. result]]]
```

```
Function[x, -2.694070753447704 + 
   x*(36.02463367942255 + x*(-414.4544969663766 + x*(2919.8339303927346 + 
         x*(-12190.359149188691 + x*(31174.896173249082 + x*(-49278.882209269956 + x*(46908.437339362164 + 
                 x*(-24621.56753111048 + 5471.459451358962*x))))))))]
```

```
Plot[function[y] - InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], y], {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-12^(-1), 1/12}}]
```

```
Function[x, -3.1981139183044434 + 
   x*(141.82176399230957 + x*(-7424.74800491333 + x*(236253.08526611328 + 
         x*(-4.680630958251953*^6 + x*(6.148906216479492*^7 + x*(-5.613556024174805*^8 + x*(3.674661709173828*^9 + 
                 x*(-1.7557128799768555*^10 + x*(6.145958481669141*^10 + x*(-1.5509398689283594*^11 + x*(2.657566083774026*^11 + 
                         x*(-2.4466979730388477*^11 + x*(-9.471151854829346*^10 + x*(6.752732365297246*^11 + 
                               x*(-9.872581110395927*^11 + x*(5.544094557729795*^11 + x*(3.4958797462575586*^11 + 
                                     x*(-8.717278427261528*^11 + x*(6.23268006496337*^11 + x*(-8.207324068464363*^10 + 
                                           x*(-1.7954943836313046*^11 + x*(1.3475389531949298*^11 + x*(-3.772789388590992*^10 + 
                                            x*(1.9975620443267794*^9 + 6.922907598366096*^8*x))))))))))))))))))))))))]
```

The maximum deviation generally stays below $0.05$ until close to the exterme values. The definition of extreme values changes by changes of $n$ values. Try values of $n$ until a satisfactory result is found.

Of course, I still may have missed something.